# presents somebody/something as adj.?

Tags: grammar

I saw the usage of this phrase in a piece of news "Clinton often presents the top two candidates as **symptomatic** of the wider party." (The news is in [this Buzzfeed article](https://www.buzzfeed.com/rubycramer/turning-to-the-general-clinton-makes-pitch-to-the-thoughtful?utm_term=.ykbJa5xp8#.pmaPRNzkJ).)

Often times I see nouns follow "present somebody/something as", while here in this sentence it is followed by an adjective "symptomatic". Is it right? Is it a common usage? who not just say "symptoms of the wider party"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Symptomatic** is used in a "something is doing something" way.
**Symptom** is used in a "something is something" way.

So the first is less dehumanizing than the second, even if they are both used insultingly. It is common, but it's more common in communities where  people try to have respect for other people.

Consider:

> This fanbase is cancer.
>   This fanbase is toxic.

Both are insulting, but saying something is cancer is meaner than describing it as toxic, however slightly.